# How can I summarize the updates to a table on an page I browse?

Tags: html, firefox, greasemonkey

I am a student at a University. With the placement process going on, we have an internal placement website that shows updates and status about various companies I have applied to. Since the number of companies is too large it becomes cumbersome to scroll through the complete list to find information. Sometimes, I just miss some things. Now, to tackle this problem, here is what I want to do:

The data is in an HTML table. Each row shows information about one company: Some dates, Status(Not/Shortlisted/Applied), Some yes/no options etc. each in a different column. Once I open the page I want to be able to extract information about which companies I got shortlisted in, and in which ones I didn't make it.

What is the right technology to do this ? I am thinking of writing a Greasemonkey user script (I have *never* actually written any, but how hard could it be ?). What other options do I have?

Edit: I don't quite understand why this question has voted to be closed?
I just displayed a use case for something general: On opening a web page, automatically extracting information from the page and display it to the user. What is the easiest and sufficiently powerful way to achieve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . When a question starts "What technology..." that has a tendency to kick off subjective debate or polling -- so it will get closed.  ... Also, SO wants questions that show effort and relevant code.  Alas, this sometimes makes it devilishly hard for beginners to know enough to get to the point to ask a SO question that won't get closed, downvoted or ignored.

Comment: @Borck okay Ill remember to phrase my questions in a manner that would avoid subjective debates. Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't get access to the website's database, Greasemonkey would be your best *automation* approach. However, this task is likely to be over before you can get a decent script up from scratch.

**Your best *practical* approach** is to save the pages and/or copy and summarize the data in MS Excel, or equivalent.

~~~~~~~~~
Here at SO, We will not develop any but the simplest Greasemonkey scripts for you from scratch  (unless they are fun somehow ;) ).  But, you can sometimes get such help in [the "Script requests forum" at userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/forums/2).

In order for someone to help you, they will need:

1. A clear idea of exactly what data gets manipulated, and how.
2. Access to the target site.  Or access to saved snapshots of the target pages.  GM scripts are extremely dependent on the details of the target page.

Comment: I was not looking for someone to code it for me ... I just wanted to know what should I code it in, thats why I did not include any code snippets. I guess Ill go with greasemonkey :)

Answer (score 0):

"other option":

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. enter `shortlisted`
3. <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>   <--repeat last search

Comment: Marc, that is all right. But the real issue is to be able to extract that information and display it on the page automatically in a fashion that would enable me absorb that information quickly. I check that page daily quite a few number of times and I'd like a more convenient way to get that information than simply searching!